# Launching an app via intent and then pressing back button closes the parent app as well

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am launching gmail app when user clicks a button. Here is my code to open gmail app on android
I am using `android_intent` package.

```
const intent = AndroidIntent(
                            action: 'android.intent.action.MAIN',
                            category: 'android.intent.category.APP_EMAIL',
                          );
                          intent.launch().catchError((e) {
                            context.showMessageDialog(e.toString());
                          });
```

It opens the `gmail` app correctly and now when I click the back button in android it closes `gmail` as well as my app. I don't want it to close my app. I want `gmail` to open as a different app. I can't use `url_launcher` package as it is used for sending email. My use case is just to open user's email app so that user can verify email which I have send from my backend during registration.

Comment: Is there any error in logcat?

Comment: @Henry No there is no error. It is opening gmail correctly. But when i press back button when i am in gmail it closes my app as well

Comment: Did you enable the "Don't keep activities" in Debug Settings of the device?

Comment: @GiuseppeGiacoppo It is not enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `AndroidManifest.xml` change `android:launchMode="singleTop"` to `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
private fun openGmail() {
    val intent = requireContext().packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.gm") //"leanback" version is for TV

    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: this looks like a kotlin code. I think the OP wants a dart/flutter code instead.